# I have 3 components on my home page how i can call it in routing in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-routing, angular-components

I have 3 components on my home page how I can call it in routing in Angular 7 because in angular routing only one component can be called with route path. Can I import other components in one component in Angular 7?

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 1):

I you want these 3 components to be seperate pages, you would need to create 3 different routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
    { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent },
    { path: 'third', component: ThirdComponent },
];
```

If you want all 3 of those components to be on one page you would do something like this in your template (.html):

```
<div>
    <my-first-component></my-first-component>
    <my-second-component></my-second-component>
    <my-third-component></my-third-component>
</div>
```